# How do I address a query letter to a publisher?

Tags: word-choice, letter-writing

I want to write a letter to an independent publisher. Enclosed with the letter is a partial manuscript of my book, which I want to mention. Here is the beginning of the letter I recently wrote to an agent:

Dear Ms X,

I am writing to seek representation for my ﬁrst novel, *XYZ*, a novel of 87,000 words; please ﬁnd enclosed the ﬁrst three chapters for your consideration, as well as a synopsis.

How to transform the above information into a decent beginning of a letter to be sent to an independent publisher? (Any tips on what else to mention in this letter is welcome.)

Here is an attempt:

To whom it may concern,

I am writing to seek a publisher for my first novel, *XYZ*, a novel of...

Could the above be better? It doesn't sound right...

Comment: Best to find out who to address by name. Also, publishers do not as a rule welcome unsolicited manuscripts.

Comment: _To whom it may concern_ is a weak opening, you should make the effort to get the name of the person that you want to read your manuscript.